# why need to specify the parameter ‘bounding_boxes’ for sample_distorted_bounding_box in tensorflow？

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```
sample_distorted_bounding_box(
    image_size,
    bounding_boxes,
    ...
)
```

> Bounding boxes are supplied and returned as [y_min, x_min, y_max, x_max]. The bounding box coordinates are floats in [0.0, 1.0] relative to the width and height of the underlying image.

the function will return a randomly distorted bounding box, why do I need specify a bounding box before I use it?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the boxes computed by this function can use the boxes provided as an input to guide the sampling.

More specifically, the random boxes returned by `sample_distorted_bounding_boxes` can be forced to contain a minimal fraction of the input bounding boxes. The goal is to avoid having bounding boxes that contains no or irrelevant information. This fraction is controled by parameter `min_object_covered` and defaults to 0.1.

Note that the input `bounding_boxes` may be empty, in which case it defaults to a single box covering the entire image.

Comment: thanks your answer. But I still can not understand what is 'contain a minimal fraction of the input bounding boxes'?

Comment: Hi, what's the relation between the number of input bounding_boxes and the returned number of distort_bbox, seems the returned distort_bbox always is 1.

Comment: @roachsinai, the returned bboxes indeed only contains one box, which refers to the cropping box randomly generated by this method, and this cropping box has to at least cover min_object_covered portion of  each of them. Alas, the naming and document of this method is very confusing. They should have named this method something like geneate_random_cropping_box(...) instead.